# Таблица асинхронных задач

Tags: java, java-8

Есть набор задач, у каждой из который есть ID. Нужно уметь задачу запускать по ID и останавливать по ID. Если задача запущена, то остановить предыдущее выполнение и начать следующее.
Задачи обернуты в `CompletableFuture`.

Очень хочется сделать это без явных блокировок на таблицу задач и использовать какой-нибудь `ConcurrentHashMap`. Но возникает вопрос как отловить случай, когда задача выполнилась быстрее вставки?

*UPDATE:* Добавил код примера того, что сейчас можно сделать с синхронизацией. Я хочу без синхронизации.
Интересует как побороть случай, когда `START_DELAY > TASK_DELAY`?

```
public class Main {
    private static final long TASK_DELAY = 100L;
    private static final long START_DELAY = 1000L;
    private final Map<Integer, CompletableFuture<Integer>> futureMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    public void start(int id) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (futureMap) {
            CompletableFuture<Integer> future = futureMap.get(id);
            if (future != null) {
                future.cancel(true);
            }
            future = executeTaskById(id);
            Thread.sleep(START_DELAY);
            future.whenComplete((a, b) -> {
                synchronized (futureMap) {
                    futureMap.remove(id);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    protected CompletableFuture<Integer> executeTaskById(int id) {
        final CompletableFuture<Integer> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
        executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TASK_DELAY);
                result.complete(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result.completeExceptionally(e);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: так-то лямбда в `whenComplete` будет вызвана, даже если на момент вызова `whenComplete` future уже будет завершено, напр. `CompletableFuture.completedFuture( 42 ).whenComplete( (i, e) -> System.out.println( "completed" ) );` выведет "completed". Вместо `remove` можно, наверное, использовать `compute( id, (k, v) -> v == future ? null : v );`, чтобы не удалить новое задание.

Answer (score 1):

"Но возникает вопрос как отловить случай, когда задача выполнилась быстрее вставки?"

сначала вставьте, потом запустите

Comment: Между вставкой и запуском можно вызвать еще раз ту же самую задачу в другом потоке. Так что это не сработает.

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy нельзя, если ее сначала надо успешно вставить, а только потом - запускать

Comment: @etki, в коде выше у меня задача создается и запускается автоматом. Я не могу этот процесс разорвать. Мне приходит уже запущенный `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy так можно не запускать ее, пока не осуществилась успешная вставка. Создать пустой CompletableFuture, вставить, в случае успеха запустить задачу и по результату обновить вставленный CompletableFuture.